# label and checkbox inline with height fix

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can I make label and checkbox inline and height equal without using `line-height` or any other css ?

Working fiddle with `line-height`(work-around) http://jsfiddle.net/yeao6ph7/3/

Fiddle without css http://jsfiddle.net/yeao6ph7/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="form">
    <form class="form-horizontal" name="myform" action="">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-3 control-label">
                <label for="inputCheckbox">Is Checked ?</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" id="inputCheckbox" value="option1"/>
                  </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Output:**

[image: with-css]

**Expected Output:**

[image: without-css]

If css is the only option, is `line-height: 35px;` right solution ? Because `input` field can be `large` as well as `small`.

Thanks,
Jigar.

---

**UPDATE**

`form-horizontal` was written incorrectly. Problem is same, fiddles updated. `line-height: 35px;` is required to adjust the height.

---

**UPDATE 2**

There are many `label` below and similarly many `input` below. So `checkbox` in the left won't help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yeao6ph7/7/

Comment: it's not the right solution

Comment: @RachelGallen 's solution seems to be a better solution, no fixed value. Much better than `line-height: some-value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed `<div class="checkbox">`

Following CSS was getting included through bootstrap:

```
.checkbox, .radio {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yeao6ph7/12/

I had added this div with class `checkbox` by following [Official Bootstrap Example](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#checkboxes-and-radios-without-la)

Answer (score 0):

Your html can just be changed so you have [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeao6ph7/8/)

As long as your input is directly related to the label then you are perfectly fine to have it in the label container.

```css
#inputCheckbox {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <form class="form-horizantable" name="myform" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-3 control-label">
        <label for="inputCheckbox">Is Checked ?
          <input type="checkbox" id="inputCheckbox" value="option1" />
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Not working. Checkbox is below in the fiddle. Also please check the update. :)

Comment: @jigar it's not for me check both my fiddela nd the run code snippet what browser are you on?

Comment: Just checked it on ie, Chrome Firefox and ophera all fine. if you are adding it to your site there must be a css rule throwing it out. do you have a link to your live site?

Comment: @DCdaz firefox. Both fiddle? I can see only one. Thanks.

Comment: @Jigar what version of firefox this could actually just be a reset issue.

Comment: Basically on `left` hand side I have all the labels and right hand side I have all the `input`.

Comment: firefox version  39.0

Comment: i am on the same firefox it doesnt make sense that if you are looking at my fiddle  that you are seeing the checkbox underneath.

Comment: Please update the fiddle and share the link again. I have the 5th version of fiddle.

Comment: Sorry you will need to be a little more clear about what it is that's going wrong are you using my fiddle?

Comment: what happens when you press run code snippet is the checkbox underneath the text?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83607/discussion-between-jigar-and-dcdaz).